# Drilling a Vault

Tags: material-science

### **Premise**

I think this is a Physics question, so i thought this would be the right stackexchange website to post my question. If I'm wrong, feel free to move the question in the right website.

I'm not a physicist so I cannot answer the question from myself, and I have not enough knowledge in physics to imagine or guess what would happen.

Also the question is just for educational purpose (I don't want to rob a bank, just to be clear).

### **Question**

The videogame series [PAYDAY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payday_2) features special [Drills](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Drills) that players have to use to drill into vault doors, reinforced doors and safes.

My question is simple: can something like this really exists? Is there some kind of machinery that can really drill something like a vault door?

### **Considerations**

I would leave apart time (in the game usually takes around up to 300 seconds to drill a vault door, around 120 for a safe big as a 22" square monitor) and size of the drills (they may be too small).

Some drills, beside the basic one that seems just like a normal drill, while other like the Thermal Drill seems to use different principles. If you think about something that could serve the same purpose but do not actually "drills" into the material, feel free to share.

**UPDATE 1**

As a comment pointed out, "We can drill through anything". I did a fast research, and I've found the exact opposite.
The Wikipedia page Bank Vault, have this [image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/WinonaSavingsBankVault.JPG) (credits to Wikimedia) where you can see on the inside of the door the writing *"STEEL: 11 Layers of Special Cutting and **Drill Resistant**"*. I think my question is still valid.

Comment: A vault door is a big slab of metal with possibly some other bits inside it. Why wouldn't we be able to drill through it? We can drill through anything. You name it and we've probably drilled through it

Comment: updated the question based on your comment @Jim

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe-cracking#Weak-point_drilling) elaborates that *drill resistant* does not mean we can't drill through it. It means we need special drills. That link, btw, details drilling as a method of safe-cracking

Comment: Please note that many/most video games are not actually based on reality and, in many cases, the laws of physics are ignored or re-written. In any event, this seems like an engineering question, not a physics question.

Comment: Ok, part of the question is asking that too. If that's possible, what do I need to serve that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Long ago I worked at a military base and we had a room size vault.  We had quantitative estimates of how long it would take to penetrate the vault under various senarios (techniques that focused on the lock or other parts).  The estimates were in the 10-20 hour range, I don't remember exactly.

In any case, it is possible to drill through the various forms of steel and other metals.  The key is you need to drill much more slowly for steel.

Here is a table of suggested drilling speeds for various metals:

http://www2.mae.ufl.edu/designlab/Lab%20Assignments/EML2322L-Drilling%20and%20Milling%20Speeds%20and%20Feeds.pdf